# Unable to create UIBackgroundModes key in Info.plist for iOS4

Tags: iphone, multitasking, info.plist

I have an audio application which works great for `iPhone 3.1.x` versions.

I am trying to upgrade it to **iOS4.0** to work in multitasking environment. When I try to create a new `UIBackgroundModes` key in `info.plist`, it ("Required Background Modes") doesn't show up in drop down list?

I also upgraded the Xcode SDK to 3.2.3, Base SDK to 4.0, deployment target to 4.0 but still `UIBackgroundModes` ("Required Background Modes") won't show up in `info.plist` drop down list.

I also created test project for 4.0, and its info.list drop down list has "Required Background Modes".

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can add the key manually by edit the .plist file

```
    <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
            <string>audio</string>
    </array>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried it but audio doesn't play in background after this. Moreover, key shows up "UIBackgroundModes" when viewing as XML property list, so I am guessing Xcode is not treating the project ready for 4.0.

Comment: You need [to do more][1] to have audio playing in background.


  [1]: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

Comment: It is an old thread though, still posting the resolution: 

Modify the .plist file manually with UIBackgroundMode tag. Although it won't show up in drop down list in xcode, but audio will play successfully in background mode.

Comment: this won't work in the simulator, only on your device

Comment: i would like to add "background fetch" in plist...What is the keyword for that please..

Answer (score 4):

Be sure that if you create the UIBackgroundModes item in Xcode (not by editing the XML manually) that you create the new key as type ARRAY, then add a new item (it will appear as "Item 0" by default) with a value of "audio".  If you simply create a string key with value "audio", it will not work.

Answer (score 3):

Re Woodmantech's answer: Xcode 3.2 changed the nomenclature a bit when adding this key in Xcode. The key is called "Required background modes" and Item 0 should be set to "App plays audio." Both are available through the GUI dropdown menu

Comment: In Xcode 5 this key now seems to be called "App plays audio or streams audio/video using AirPlay"