# multitasking iphone sdk- uibackgroundmodes not working with audio?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, audio, ios4, multitasking

Hey, 
I am working on an application that streams mp3 audio of the internet. it is a radio application and now I would like to add multitasking functionality but unfortunately it isn't working. the audio shuts off as soon as the application goes into background. the mp3 streamer is using audiotoolbox. How can I multitask? I have tried the uibackgroundmodes by adding it in plist (had to add it manually by going into text file because it wasn't showing up in the drop down menu may be this could the reason why but I am not sure what to do if this is the reason). So my question is clear is there anything else I have to do in order to make my application multitask? is there anything I am missin (well sure I am but not sure what). Any code would be appreciated 
thanks, 
TC

Answer (score 1):

If you've correctly edited the Info.plist, to allow background audio (see [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3251793/unable-to-create-uibackgroundmodes-key-in-info-plist-for-ios4)), then if audio started it should play when app enters background. Quote from Apple [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html):

> As long as it is playing audio or video content, the application continues to run in the background to support that content. However, if the application stops playing that audio or video, the system suspends it. Similarly, if the application does not include the appropriate key in its Info.plist file, the application becomes eligible for suspension immediately upon entering the background.

Comment: I have made sure that everything is hooked up properly. I am using mp3 streamer from this web page: http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/09/streaming-and-playing-live-mp3-stream.html I just wanted to know if I can multi task on this (I am pretty sure there is a way). So please I really want to know how to do this my project has come to halt.. thanks.

Comment: Great though the linked article is, things have moved on - look at the newer iOS frameworks .. this link is a start: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingAudio/UsingAudio.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009767-CH2-SW6