# Prevent app to crash when I open multitask

Tags: iphone, ios, multitasking

When my app is launched, and I double tap on the home button to display the bottom bar containing all the running application (multitasking), My App crashes, and I have no idea where it can come from !!

Any help please ?

Comment: Please provide the crash log and the stack trace.

Comment: Check is that your iphone is support the multitasking or not .if yes than register you app for background task go in to the plist put this Required background mode like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3251793/unable-to-create-uibackgroundmodes-key-in-info-plist-for-ios4

Comment: @Harish that makes not sense, since the app switch tray is only present on phones that do multitasking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found it, actually I had nothing in the stack nor in the console log, except a "Program ended with exit code: 255", but that's I quit the application in the applicationWillResignActive, using exit(-1). Thanks anyway