# Standard iPhone app that runs as a background service, jail-broken or not

Tags: iphone, ios

is it possible to implement an iphone app that runs as a background service? Or does it need to be jailbroken?  It seems from the iPhone UI that most apps  stopped running when you press the home button, with the exception of the music apps and pandora, etc. They still run even when user close the app UI.

Comment: What kind of background service?

Comment: @robert: a background service that changes my location to a random location every hour.

Comment: what do you mean by "changes my location"?  are you spoofing your location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is not possible, as you said you will have to have a jailbroken iphone in order to do that

Comment: pandora seems to be running on the background though, or is that different?

Comment: @JunbaTester, audio, VOIP, and location apps can stay alive in the background, using the a key [in your Info.plist file](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3252100/119114)

Comment: @JunbaTester With location apps not meaning apps that change the location but listen to location changes!

Comment: @Nate: is there a way to programmatically change the my current location?

Comment: @JunbaTester thats not what nate meant, what he meant is application that uses GPS to track your location

Comment: Correct.  What Omar said :).  I still don't know what @JunbaTester means when he/she says "change my current location".

Answer (score 0):

To execute a task every hour, you can pretend to be a voip application.
For this, add the "voip" attribute to the UIBackgrounding key of your Info.plist.
After start, call [UIApplication setKeepAliveTimeout:3600 handler:^{ ... your code ... }];
Your handler will be executed every hour.

See: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW12